# Spring-boot method does not exist error while starting

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, web-services, jboss

I am working on a basic spring-boot application with rest-api call and deploying it in jboss6.3 server, but getting an error from embedded tomcat server clash.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.panacea</groupId>
  <artifactId>Panacea-API-point</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Panacea-API-point Maven Plugin</name>

  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
<!--        <relativePath /> lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

error in console:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getDefaultLifecycleListeners(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:159)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable()Z
```

The method's class, org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/D:/IDC/jboss-eap-6.3_JAXRS_1.6/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-6.3.3.CP/org/jboss/as/web/main/jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/org/apache/catalina/core/AprLifecycleListener.class
vfs:/D:/IDC/jboss-eap-6.3_JAXRS_1.6/standalone/deployments/Panacea.ear/Panacea-API-point-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar/org/apache/catalina/core/AprLifecycleListener.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/D:/IDC/jboss-eap-6.3_JAXRS_1.6/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-6.3.3.CP/org/jboss/as/web/main/jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener

Comment: Are you trying to run in embedded tomcat? If yes you can try changing the provided scope to compile for spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Comment: No, I don't want to use that embedded tomcat server

Comment: is main class extends SpringBootServeltInitializer and overriden configure method for deploying application in external servers?

Comment: yes done that also

Comment: @smootherbug how you resolved this issue?